# How to add a quick action only for salesforce 1, not for lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am working on a Lightning migration project where I need to migrate my existing Vf pages to lightning experience and salesforce 1 mobile app, but classic will continue to be in use.
I have a inline Vf in detail page layout that I am rendering only when the user theme is classic and for lightning experience mode I am using record home page customized via lightning app builder where I have added my lightning component in side bar.

For salesforce1 mobile app I am using quick actions.I want this quick action to appear only when I am viewing the record in mobile. How this quick action can be rendered conditionally?
The lightning component basically shows the list of related records along with some functionality to edit delete etc

Correct me if something is wrong in my approach

[image: UI in lightning experience]

[image: Quick action]

Comment: Did you solve this?